# Does ROS include the boost libraries?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the boost uBLAS library which contains functions for matrices. Now my question is does ROS include the boost libraries?

If yes why do I get the error displayed below? I checked out http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Using_Boost and believe I do everything correct. I am only including the header files at the moment.

If no where do I have to extract the boost package (the .tar file) which one can download from the boost website, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html? When I look to the last line of the error I see that I should have unpacked them in either `/usr`  `/usr/include/`  or `/usr/lib`?

Error

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:892
> (message):
> [rosboost-cfg --libs uBLAS] failed with error: Traceback (most recent
> call
> last):
>
> ```
>   File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosboost-cfg",
> ```
>
> line 35, in 
> rosboost_cfg.main()
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py",
> line 359, in main
> output = lflags(ver, options.lflags.split(','))
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py",
> line 278, in lflags
> s += lib_flags(ver, lib) + " "
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py",
> line 268, in lib_flags
> lib = find_lib(ver, name)
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py",
> line 249, in find_lib
> raise BoostError('Could not locate library [%s], version %s in lib
> directory [%s]'%(name, ver, dir))
>
> ```
> rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError:
> ```
>
> "Could not locate library [uBLAS],
> version (1, 46, 1, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True) in lib
> directory
> [/usr/lib]"
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:26 (rosbuild_link_boost)

Source

```
// Include boost libs                                                           
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>                                       
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
```

CMakelist.txt

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()                                                
rosbuild_link_boost(wallDetector uBLAS)                                         
rosbuild_add_executable(wallDetector src/wallDetector.cpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80916/does-ros-include-the-boost-libraries?/) by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay most I found out that most linux systems include several pre-built boost libraries. I also found out that most of the boost libraries actually don't have to be built separately since they only exists out of header files. So what I did was just Downloaded the boost libraries from the website. Extracted the folder `/usr/local`. Then I just ran `bootstrap.sh` and I could include the header files in my own C++ files and compile.

For more info: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

---

Originally posted by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) with karma: 109 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0